# PySpark + ElasticSearch: Reading multiple index/type

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running PySpark with Elasticsearch back using the Elasticsearch-hadoop connector.  I can read from a desired index using:

```
    es_read_conf = {
        "es.nodes": "127.0.0.1",
        "es.port": "9200",
        "es.resource": "myIndex_*/myType"
    }
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("devproj")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
        keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
        valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
        conf=es_read_conf
    )
```

Works fine.  I can wildcard the index.

How do I wildcard the document "type"?  Or, how could I get more than one type, or even `_all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all types you can use "es.resource": "myIndex_*".

For the wildcard part you would need a query:

```
     "prefix": {
        "_type": {
          "value": "test"
        }
      }
```

Comment: okay, this worked.  If I leave out the "type", it will select "all types"